# Symfony : Why Factory Proxy has values in ChangeSet even though the request failed?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, api-platform.com

I'm using API Platform and factories to run my tests. I want to patch a User by changing their name, and get a validation constraint error (resulting in a http 422 response). But it looks like when I autorefresh my User ($user->object()) afterwards, the UnitOfWork computes the name change in the changeset. I don’t get it as my Patch, only takes an array (so I’m not editing the actual User) as a parameter...

I tried to dump some variables to have more information but I'm stuck. Here's what I have :

```
$this->createClientWithCredentials($user->object())->request('PATCH', $path, ['json' => [
        'firstName' => 'wrong name',
        'email' => 'not a valid email',
    ], 'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/merge-patch+json']]);
    self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame(Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    self::assertResponseHeaderSame('content-type', 'application/ld+json; charset=utf-8');
    self::assertJsonContains([
        'violations' => [
            [
                'propertyPath' => 'email',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
    dump($user);
    dump($user->object());
```

On the first dump, $user is a `Proxy` and the property `object` contains my user with the original values.

On the second dump, $user will have 'wrong name' as firstName and 'not a valid email' as email.

The changeSet I dump from inside the Proxy::object() method (dumping $object property EntityChangeSet) outputs the two fields, with the previous values as key 0, and the new values (which shouldn't have been computed) as key 1

I must add that autoRefresh is set to true (default behavior, no problem anywhere else). Which cause the `object()` method to perform a refresh. This refresh is not performed because there are "unsaved changes". I don't know when those values enter the UnitOfWork...

Am I doing something wrong?